# How to bind an image to the ListView.GroupHeader ?

Tags: listview, xamarin

I'm listing today's matches inside a listView on the home page , I used the listView.GroupHeaderTemplate to show teams together which are in the same league.
 For now my listView looks like;

Premier League

Manchester city vs  ....

Liverpool       vs ...

I just want to add image in front of the Premier league header.

I try to bind an image_link but it's not possible , because when I try to bind inside the GroupHeader.Template, image don't showing up. When I bind to same image_link outside of the GroupHeader.Template ,the image showing up .

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can build it with this structure:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Image Source="..."/>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <Image Source="{Binding link}"/>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate> .   

That's exactly what I'm doing.However , it's not working. If I write  <Image Source="{Binding link}"/> outside of the GroupHeaderTemplate it's working but i want to write it inside.

Comment: Do you use `IsGroupingEnabled="true"` ?

Comment: Yes i'm using . I already grouped Items, but I want to add image in front of that group names

Comment: Therefore, the problem is with the property in the Binding. Specify in your Key that you use for Grouping the Image source as you do with the Title like Premier League.